# Indian Election Data

Tags: data

I am in a project to study Indian elections.

I need election candidates affidavits which includes financial disclosures. I am working with elections 2009 and 2014.

The main source of this information in the [Election Commission of India](http://eci.gov.in/).
But I cannot access it here in Australia.

Does anyone know any alternatives?